# unable to fix the height of the tab page in facebook

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-tabs

Using tab application in Face book,i am unable to set the height of the iframe which is always set to 800.
I have tried so many variations but nothing works for me.

```
FB.Canvas.setSize({ width: 640, height: 1480 });
FB.Canvas.setAutoResize();
FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow();
```

By the way i am using v2.9.
Can you please suggest me how to remove the scrollbar and show full page ?

Comment: Have you embedded and initialized the SDK before calling this? What does the browser console say?

Comment: Yup,i have. No error in the console

Comment: Can you show this live?